Example of a Graph Where Every Node is Pivotal for at Least Two Different Pairs of Nodes
I’m working through an example in graph theory using the concept of a pivotal node. A node (X) is considered pivotal for a pair of distinct nodes (Y) and (Z) if (X) lies on every shortest path between (Y) and (Z) (and (X) is not equal to either (Y) or (Z)).
Question: Give an example of a graph in which every node is pivotal for at least two different pairs of nodes.
I can not think of any, does it exist an answer or not?


HINT: Consider a cycle on at least $9$ vertices. You can draw a picture to see that indeed, a cycle $C$ on $9$ or more vertices is such that every vertex on $C$ is pivotal for at least $2$ pairs of vertices.[And note by the symmetry of $C$ you only need to check that one vertex of $C$ is pivotal for at least two pairs!]
In fact, won't the cycles on $8$,$7$ vertices do as well, as @user14111 noted below.

$C_7$ is good enough, since the question only asks for two different pairs of nodes, not two disjoint pairs. Another example is the Cartesian product $C_n\square C_n$ where $n\ge5$.

@user14111 indeed the cycles on $8$ or $7$ vertices will work. But $C_9$ certainly suffices as does any cycle on more vertices.
